How do I use fewer private clauses for OpenMP tasks?
I am learning the tasking API of OpenMP right now, but I am confused on how to use the private clause when making tasks to make threads have independent copies of a variable that has been declared outside the #pragma omp sections
Consider the code below:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>

int main(){

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
{
  int tid;
  #pragma omp single private(tid)
    {

      tid = omp_get_thread_num();
      printf("[A from thread %d] ", tid);
     
   #pragma omp task private(tid)
     {
       tid = omp_get_thread_num();
       printf("[race from thread %d] ", tid);
     }

   #pragma omp task private(tid)
     {
       tid = omp_get_thread_num();
       printf("[car from thread %d] ",tid);
     }
    }
 } 
return 0;
}

All this code is supposed create a parallel section with a pool of 4 thread and each  thread from the pool is assigned one or more tasks declared under #pragma omp task.
The serial version of this program must just print A race car, but I since I want to know which thread from the pool is printing which word, I am putting square brackets around each word with the thread number.

My question is I am declaring the variable int tid near the beginning of the program. I want to be sure that each thread executing a task has its own private copy of tid so that these copies are not subject to race conditions.
So in order to do that, I have placed repeated the private(tid) clause in a bunch of places. Is there a way to reduce this repetition of code?

Best practice is to declare the variable in the innermost applicable scope. This safes you from puting private everywhere. If you don't use the result other than passing it to a function argument, why would you assign the value to a variable in the first place?

This is not C++, please don't spam tags. Also, why are you posting an image of text?

@PasserBy Because that is the output of the compilation and the run that is displayed. And yes that is C++, if you switch it out gcc with g++ it will compile just fine. I am only using the OpenMP extensions of the language.

The source code coincidentally being valid C++ doesn't affect its behaviour as a C program. You're compiling it as a C program, so it's not C++. Images of text only ever cause problems, the program output is no different.

@PasserBy Okay dude whatever.

While I agree with @PasserBy, "Images of text only ever cause problems" is a rather lazy way to avoid explaining the issue. Fortunately there is a canonical meta-Q&A about this topic: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Just copy textual output into a code block.

@paleonix On the other hand, one could expect a member with 14.6k reputation to know that...

@PierU depends on how that reputation was achieved - I haven't checked. Days active might be a better indicator idk.
